# how to parse ko.observable string received from json to integer (number) value

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, observable

I am getting a String in my ViewModel from json response from server.
it looks like this:

```
"manual_setpoint": "200",
```

I then need to display it in my view:

```
<div class="setpoint"  data-bind="text: vm.manual_setpoint(), style: { color: vm.state()? '#f00000' : '#777777'}"></div>
```

It needs to be display as a number 20 (200/10), because there are buttons for increasing and decreasaing that observable (eg. 201->20.1, 199->19.9). This was not problem while my observable was defined localy as a number. I did it like this:

```
   self.manual_setpoint.formatted = function() {
     return (self.manual_setpoint() / 10);
   };
```

and then displayed manual_setpoint.formatted() in my view.I aslo had buttons for increasing and decreasing this observable like this:

```
self.decSetpoint = function (observable) {
decrement(observable);
};

var decrement = function (observable) {
observable(observable() - 1);
};
```

Now when the response from server is String, my methods no longer work.
(eg. for 200 + 1 I get 2001 etc....)

how to handle this situation in a most simple and elegant way?
I need to have proper number displayed in my view (so for 200 I need 20) and I must be able to
incremenat and decrement that same observable like before

Comment: Can you update the JSON so it's sent as a number there rather than a string, since that would appear to be the underlying issue?

Comment: Unfortunatly I am not able to change JSON.
Also, this is a interesting situation, that I thought would be easy to solve. But ko.js is somewhat complicated in that sense, so I would like to learn how to solve it

Comment: How is it converted from server JSON data to an observable?

Comment: It is handled inside the ko.js app using ko.map.fromjs, but it is irrelevant for the question.

Answer (score 2):

following on from @johndoe's comment  - respectfully, I disagree.  Happy to remove the answer if I have misunderstood the question.

If the value is sent as a string in the JSON and mapped via ko.map.fromJs then chances are very good that it has been mapped as `ko.observable("200")` rather than `ko.observable(200)`  if that is the case then I see that you can a couple of things

1. Do something about mapping to convert the value to an integer/float which should make the `decrement()` function work as expected; or
2. change the decrement function to convert the value, like the following.

   ```
   var decrement = function (observable) {
      observable(parseInt(observable()) - 1);
   };
   ```

I would also change

```
   self.manual_setpoint.formatted = function() {
     return (self.manual_setpoint() / 10);
   };
```

to

```
   self.manual_setpoint.formatted = ko.pureComputed(function() {
     return (self.manual_setpoint() / 10);
   });
```

so that when manual_setpoint is changed the formatted version gets updated as well.

**EDIT**

Well, I stand corrected on needing to use a pureComputed for the formatted function.  Using this basic test it appears that just using a function works as expected.  For a long time it has been my understanding that adding a function that wraps an observable in some way would execute once and would not update if the wrapped observable was updated after the wrapping function had been executed (usually during the binding process).  so when the view was bound to the wrapping function, the view would not be updated because the returned function was not observable.

Also it looks like the parseInt not really required either based on the test probably because the function is doing a division.  i think my experience has been based on adding which results in things like `"20" + 1 = "201"` instead of `20 + 1 = 21`

Hopefully the tests below help you as much they have helped me.

```js
var app = window.app || {};

app.vm = new Vm();

function Vm(){
  var self = this;
  self.manual_setpoint = ko.observable("200");
  self.manual_setpoint.formatted =  function() {
     return (parseInt(self.manual_setpoint()) / 10);
  };
  self.manual_setpoint.formattedAsComputed =  ko.pureComputed(function() {
     return (self.manual_setpoint() / 10);
  });
  self.state = ko.observable(true);
  
  self.increment = function(){
    var value = parseInt(self.manual_setpoint()) + 1;
    self.manual_setpoint(value.toString());
  };
  self.decrement = function(){
    var value = parseInt(self.manual_setpoint()) - 1;
    self.manual_setpoint(value.toString());
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(app);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="setpoint"  data-bind="text: vm.manual_setpoint(), style: { color: vm.state()? '#f00000' : '#777777'}"></div>
<div class="setpoint"  data-bind="text: vm.manual_setpoint, style: { color: vm.state()? '#f00000' : '#777777'}"></div>
<div class="setpoint"  data-bind="text: vm.manual_setpoint.formatted(), style: { color: vm.state()? '#f00000' : '#777777'}"></div>
<div class="setpoint"  data-bind="text: vm.manual_setpoint.formatted, style: { color: vm.state()? '#f00000' : '#777777'}"></div>

<div class="setpoint"  data-bind="text: vm.manual_setpoint.formattedAsComputed, style: { color: vm.state()? '#f00000' : '#777777'}"></div>
<div class="setpoint"  data-bind="text: vm.manual_setpoint.formattedAsComputed(), style: { color: vm.state()? '#f00000' : '#777777'}"></div>

<button data-bind="click: vm.increment">Increment</button>
<button data-bind="click: vm.decrement">Decrement</button>
<br/>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(vm)"></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please explaina  bit more about why the pure computed makes a difference?
Also, will the value of self.manual_setpoint (when passing it back to server) be a string or a number?